# How can I release resdhift resources on aws lambda timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am not able to caught error on lambda timeout. I want to release few write locks on the tables is lambda goes timed out.
How can I release resdhift resources on aws lambda timeout?

Comment: If your process runs for a long time, it might not be a good idea to use Lambda. Go for Data Pipeline or lightsail(haven't used this one yet). Lambda helps to execute a large number of tiny tasks without actually maintaining a server.

Comment: nightgaunt Thanks for quick reply. By my script is not taking much time, Even some how if it goes time out how can I release db resources. Actually I am not able to caught lambda timeout error in my code. I am using python 2.7. I want to catch timeout error and want to release db resources. If you have any idea how can I detect in my code if my lambda has been time out. it would me really helpful for me.

Comment: What "db resources" are you wanting to 'release'?

Comment: I have locked redshift table inside transactional block in lambda and if in case lambda goes timeout I want to release lock on the table. Now I am not getting any clue how can I release the lock and due to this lock no any other queries can be run by same/other user.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "catch" an AWS Lambda timeout. When your Lambda function times-out, your code simply stops.

You need to (a) avoid timeouts in your code, and (b) your code must be OK if it does time-out.

If you cannot do the above, then Lambda may not be the right service for your use-case.